# ASP.NET Core application exe how to configure it and what is it running in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created an ASP.NET Core 6.0 application in  VS 2022.
When it builds in debug mode it creates a bunch of files in bin/Debug/net6.0 directory.
One of them is .exe
I can run it and it opens a purple command line window where it reports running in Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime and shows a url on which it runs.
I assume that executable starts up an instance of Kestrel with my ASP.NET Core app in it?
Running this app inside Visual Studio results in the app hosted on ports that I could trace down to launchSettings.json file.

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: https://localhost:7053
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: http://localhost:5105
```

Obviously I can change these ports in launchSettings.json, but it only has effect when I run it in VS
If I run the exe file instead (the one in bin\Debug\net6.0), the ports are always 5000 and 5001

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

How do I configure those ports (so instead of 5000 and 5001 I can specify different numbers? 
Also can I make the url contain some name so instead of

```
http://localhost:5000 and https://localhost:5001
```

it's

```
http://localhost/MyApp1 and https://localhost/MyApp1
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link posted by Quing Guo 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0

the answer for configuring ports while running exe from bin\Debug\net6.0 directory is to add the following section to appsettings.json (in that same directory):

```
"Kestrel": {
"Endpoints": {
  "Http": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:5002"
  },
  "Https": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:5003"
  }
 }
},
```

Second part of the question (how to redirect from https://{server}:{port} to https://{server}/{path} is still unanswered, but can be addressed in this one:

[How to configure nginx Windows to forward requests to web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973052/how-to-configure-nginx-windows-to-forward-requests-to-web-apps)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure those ports (so instead of 5000 and 5001 I can
> specify different numbers?

Yes , you can.

> Also can I make the url contain some name?

Sorry, maybe you cannot,
you can set url like :`{scheme}://{loopbackAddress}:{port}`

From [Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0) we can see:

> ASP.NET Core projects are configured to bind to a random HTTP port
> between 5000-5300 and a random HTTPS port between 7000-7300. This
> default configuration is specified in the generated
> Properties/launchSettings.json file and can be overridden.

In your **launchSettings.json** file override the `applicationUrl` :

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8001;http://localhost:8000"
```

result:

[image]

**Update:**

> specifically running the exe file located in bin\Debug\net6.0 In that
> case launchSettings.json has no effect

In this case , you can refer to [Configure(IConfiguration)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configureiconfiguration-1) to set ports in section to appsettings.json :

```
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you got my question. I am trying to run it OUTSIDE of VS, specifically running the exe file located in bin\Debug\net6.0 In that case  launchSettings.json has no effect.

Comment: However looking at your link I did find the answer for configuring ports. So thank you.

Comment: If you rephrase your answer to match mine I am happy to accept yours as an answer to give you credit

Comment: @ILIA BROUDNO Thank you for your feedback :) I rephrase my answer to match yours. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm. The thing is the question specifically says when running OUTSIDE of VS so part of your answer that's still referring to  launchSettings.json is plain incorrect. My question in fact mentions launchSettings.json and  makes it clear that I know how to do it there and that it's NOT what I am asking. I'm going to accept my answer as this is the one that's correct. Sorry. The unanswered part of the question still remains - how to redirect from https://localhost:5001 to https://localhost/MyApp1  but I made a separate question to address that.