# How to Self Host a .NET WebAPI Console App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to create a simple Console app that acts as a local host server. The point of this app is to communicate with another .net app.

I have successfully created that app and can run it fine from within Visual Studio. However, when I try to run the app from console or another .net app (using Process.Start). It does not work as intended.

From what I understand, this is because it needs to be self hosted?

The tutorial I used to create the webapi app is [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-convert-console-project-to-web-api-project/). So my Program.cs looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting program");
    SetupHostAndServices();
}

private async static void SetupHostAndServices()
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
    host.Run();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHost =>
              {
                  webHost.UseStartup<Startup>();
              }).ConfigureServices(services => 
              {
              });
}
```

To start the webapi console app from my other app I am doing this:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = GetServicePath(type),
    Arguments = args,
    UseShellExecute = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
};
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo = StartInfo,
};
process.Start();
```

When the console app starts, it does not perform the same was as it does in Visual studio. For instance, it is listening to port 5000 which is not the port I defined in my LaunchSettings.json file. It also seems to get stuck in a weird POST loop.

Comment: The "weird POST loop" part should be a separate post; one question per post.  You should remove that part so it doesn't get closed for needing more focus.

Comment: [similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955421/asp-net-core-application-exe-how-to-configure-it-and-what-is-it-running-in) and look at documents [Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: @madreflection The "Weird POST loop" is a result of the the app not being properly hosted. Which is why it doesn't need a separate thread. It is simply me explaining that things aren't working in the current state.

Comment: I think launchsettings.json is only for local development

Comment: @NickHudson: If it's relevant, then you haven't provided enough information to confirm that it's actually part of the cause (not just a symptom) and use that information to resolve the hosting issue. If you don't need to provide more information to resolve the hosting issue, then it's noise and it should be removed.

Comment: @madreflection Not sure if you are reading the full post. Again, the "Post loop" happens because I have no hosting setup. Which is why I get weird results when running the app outside of the VS environment. I also explained this in the second paragraph here.
"I have successfully created that app and can run it fine from within Visual Studio. However, when I try to run the app from console or another .net app (using Process.Start). It does not work as intended. (This is when the POST loop happens).

From what I understand, this is because it needs to be self hosted?"

Comment: No, I read it. There's no indication of what a "POST loop" is or how it manifests. You just expect us to understand what that means. GH DevOps is basically right, in that only Visual Studio uses that file, and Ibram Reda's comment links to the relevant information for setting the URLs by various means. Again, focus on the hosting issue. Follow Ibram Reda's link and read the article. Maybe the "POST loop" will be fixed as a matter of course, making it noise. If it's not, it's caused by something else and deserves to be a separate post.

Comment: @IbramReda Setup Kestel hosting and everything is running smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: @madreflection I added that bit in there just to show that things were not working correctly due to the hosting. I did not feel it needed an explanation and it was not meant to be a question. If you think it was noise, then that's your opinion. IMO this whole comment thread is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Kestel for self hosting. My host builder looks like this now:

```
var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder();
var app = builder
  .UseKestrel(options => options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 60676))
  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot"))
  .Configure(app =>
  {
      app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
      {
          FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")),
          RequestPath = "/"
      });
  }).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
app.Run();
```